# Passing jQuery's in-build functions as callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

Very often in jQuery I need to call for in-build function (hide, show, slideDown, etc) and usually we call them via anonymous wrap function:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('div').animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 2000, function() { $(this).hide() })
})
```

Is there a way to pass these functions by reference like this?

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('div').animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 2000, $(this).hide)
})
```

I guess it's not possible due to way jQuery adds this functions to objects, but it would be nice if somebody can eloborate why the problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you've tried it because the call to `hide` won't have the context of `$(this)`. You can do it that way by binding the function you pass as a callback to the object it needs to be called on:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').animate({
        opacity: 0.25
    }, 2000, $.fn.hide.bind($(this)));
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/WYkTs/).

Comment: Seems that 'this' referes to button, not a div

Comment: @the_ghost - Yes, it will refer to the button since it's inside the button click callback... you could replace the argument to `bind` with whatever collection you like though.